# Multiple tinymce usage in single page

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using tinymce for multiple instances in single page, at times when i try to use Tinymce. tinymce is not working as expected.[image]

Here is the screenshot of issue

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey for me one tinymce is working properly and another is not working in some times

Comment: it would be nice to some of your code, so we can narrow the problem down

Comment: I got solution by modifying angular-tinymce.js

Answer (score 0):

```
attrs.$set('id', ID_ATTR + '-' + (new Date().valueOf()));
```

Change the above line:

```
var generatedIds = 0;

// generate an ID

if (!attrs.id) {
    attrs.$set('id', 'uiTinymce' + generatedIds++);
}
```